# PHP uploaded image gets truncated

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I have a form that uploads images < 500kb
The issue I'm encountering is that the uploaded image on the server is partially visible / missing part of the image.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];  //reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
    if ($image) //if it is not empty
    {   
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']); //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
        $extension = getExtension($filename);//get the extension of the file in a lower case format
        $extension = strtolower($extension);

        if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")){
            echo '<h1>Error, allowed only: .jpg, .png, .gif</h1>';
            $errors=1;
        }else{
            $size = filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

            if ($size > 512000){
                echo '<h1 style="color:red;">Too big (Max: 500KB). Try again. </h1>';
                $errors=1;
            }else{ //MAX SIZE IS SMALLER

                $s = $_POST['first_name'];
                $ts = array("/ä/","/Ä/");
                $tn = array("a","A");



                $image_name= preg_replace($ts,$tn, str_replace(' ','+',$s)).'_'.time().'.'.$extension; // $image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
                $newname="img/uploads/images/".$image_name;

                $copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
                if (!$copied)
                {
                    echo '<h1>Could not upload image</h1>';
                    $errors=1;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

^^^^ more of image is missing

Comment: @all thought was irrelevant. adding it now

Comment: It could be the browser caching the image, a partial upload or a rendering problem. 
Show some of your code but also physically download the image (with FTP) and look at it without your browser to narrow down what's up.

Comment: using move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname) may help but other than that the code looks fine. Is there a problem with the uploaded file? Can you attach that too?

Comment: the image I found on the server and it's partially grayed, and opening it in PS it says "This document might be damaged (the file might be truncated or incomplete)"

Comment: Concur with @AndyGee: temporary upload files should not be manipulated other than by `move_uploaded_file()`. On a PHP 5.1 (IIRC), Apache 2.x/Scientific Linux, I had a `copy()` return all zero-length files. This might well be a similar issue.

Comment: @AndyGee uploaded the image, as you can see there's missing 20% of the image, but it varies from upload to upload, sometimes is only visible 15%. Not sure how to use move_image in my case, looking at the DOCS now

Comment: The image you uploaded is truncated so it's fair to assume the file didn't complete uploading. Maybe the temporary directory is full on the server, maybe you're over your quota on your server. I've tested your code on my server and there's no problems here.

Comment: @AndyGee thanks so much for taking the time to test! really kind from you. And great heads up in discovering what's actually going on. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @lserni if I use `move_uploaded_file` I  got the error: `Unable to move '/tmp/phpnkm7Ix' to '(my path to foldername bla bla)'`

Comment: This strongly indicates something is not right on the server. Does not look like either permission problems or disk space, though. But I notice that your image is an exact multiple of 1024 bytes, which is uncommon (is it true of all damaged images? They are truncated so that their size is an integer multiple of 1024?). Is there nothing in the webserver logs? Is some other software (proxy, antivirus, ...) interfering? Try uploading from a different PC and see what happens.

Comment: @Iserni I contacted the provider... the server disc was 100%. Thanks all for your help!!! you might post some possible options in an answer, ... for future users, seems banal but I lost 3h of my life :)

Comment: I'll leave it to @AndyGee, he was the one who suspected disk space. From the fact that newer images *did* arrive, if partially, I had thought it couldn't be that simple :-)

Comment: @AndyGee / Lserni fair enough. Waiting for an answer to approve/accept. THanks again for all your effort guys

Comment: First things first. Have you tried with a different image? Can you compare the file size of the local image and the one on the server?

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes, with smaller images (20 - 80KB) I had no issues, but after uploading a bigger image... bam! Image was truncated.

Comment: Can you compare the exact image sizes?

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes, the cut one is smaller, but if you read our comments the question is resolved.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see that. All is well then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image you uploaded is truncated so it's fair to assume the file didn't complete uploading. Maybe the temporary directory is full on the server, maybe you're over your quota on your server. I've tested your code on my server and there's no problems here.